# Are special characters in names commonplace enough to test for?

Tags: test-design, internationalization

If folks use special characters in their names, e.g. names like

```
Amélie, Jôse, 王
```

I will test that we can store them.

My question is whether people use these names on the web in the US?  Or do folks ignore the accents when typing?  You would need to go to some effort as a user to setup and use the special characters after all and I can imagine that a lot of sites can't handle special characters perhaps.  We collect names in order to give car insurance quotes and we also pass on the data to other providers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, **yes**. A bit longer a story:

> on the web in the US

Actually there is no such thing. Worldwide is the name of the game.

> names like Amélie, Jôse, 王

Accents and such ARE important. People from France or Spain or Korea would have their own computer support for these special characters as a matter of course. They usually keep them when moving, for example, to the States. Your name is precious. Not all folks will adapt for easy acceptance while integrating in the new environment.

> car insurance quotes

Best verify what the people in Quotes accept. There should be some guidelines. And in Invoices :-) Generic banking requirements may help here. Non-alphabetic character sets like 王 may be out for procedural reasons.

> and we also pass on the data

Also better check out what the receiving parties support. There SHOULD be something written down as it is beyond company borders. Or you can scrutinize what you, in turn, receive from them. Last resort, that.

The technical side: Best keep names separate from the OS. So avoid filenames. Check/test database support settings.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge there is no such thing if there is English language or keyword. For such characters it would go as a part of I18N testing depending on which level is important for project.

Comment: Can you give more information?

Comment: There are 3 levels of I18N testing. Level 0, Level 1 and Level 2. Level 0 includes just verify that web site contents converted to particular language. In this level, tester may not have knowledge of particular language. Level 2 means tester should have knowledge of particular language and contents should be verified as per language selected. Even it includes entered text in text box. Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: What is level 1?

Comment: I am not sure but in level 1 developers are adding some character and testers verify that if character displays for particular language and confirms that it has been converted to specific language properly. e.g. if English needs to translated to french then developer will add character as ^ after each word and testers verify that ^ character displayed after each character in french.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, people will use there proper names on the web. People may use accented characters. Certain names, specially last names also have an apostrophe, for example,

> O'Neil, O'Connor, O'Brian

in U.S. or otherwise. Many a times there also suffix like

> "Jr.", "Sr.", "III", "IV"

and so on.

All these are valid names including the one you mention in your question. People will definitely use the names as they are on the web regardless of their location. You need to make sure that you have defined proper quality criteria depending on your expected user-base and verify that your software meets them.

Happy Testing :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! We are an international company that builds HR software which impacts employees' hours, paychecks and payroll - testing for special characters is not optional. I highly suggest you always include special characters in test data such as names, especially when communicating with a device such as mobile or exporting data to another program, such as MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you deal with international audience, use Unicode. People outside of USA routinely use native keyboards with special characters, especially when they copy-paste info to your forms.